TypeScript: VS Code's intellisense for depending properties
I have this JSON:
const example = {
  admin: {
    name: "Name",
  },
  greeting: "Hello",
};

I can get the main keys in TS like this:
type Keys = keyof typeof example;

I can write a function like this:
const myFunc = (key: Keys)=>{
    ///...
}

And I can call it like this:
myFunc('admin')

And I cannot call it like this:
myFunc('Non-existing key')

How can I write a function like the following and enjoy VS Code's intellisense, so that it would give me suggestion for name?
myFunc('admin.name')
// OR
myFunc('admin', 'name')


See the linked q/a for how to do this; if I apply that answer here I get the code at this playground link.
